# Trouble with Cross Compiling Asterisk

Tags: cross-compiling, asterisk

I've trying to Cross Compile Asterisk for Armhf platform. 
I was using *g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf && gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf* packages for cross-compiling Asterisk with 2 following prerequisite : 
SQlite3 :

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
>   make && make install

Ncurses :

> ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   make && make install

When I cross compile Asterisk :

> ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --prefix=MY_RESULT_DEST_DIR --disable-xmldoc --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
>   make menuselect && make && make install

It works great, but thing I dont understand is that why the configure script recognize my ncurses && sqlite3 result directory?

Bug appears when I install ncurses and sqlite3 on particular directories, and then configure asterisk source with 2 params --with-ncurses && --with-sqlite3,

> ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --prefix=MY_RESULT_DEST_DIR --disable-xmldoc --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --with-ncurses=NCURSES_RESULT --with-sqlite3=SQLITE3_RESULT

It works for configuring but failed for making, and the following error thrown with make

> checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
>   checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
>   checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
>   checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
>   configure: error: termcap support not found
>   make[1]: *** [editline/libedit.a] Error 1
>
>   make: *** [main] Error 2

So, what should I do to fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Dang Loi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, thank you arheops.

I did edit the main/editline/configure file by turning *ac_cv_lib_$ac_lib_var* into yes to bypass the termcap checking when running make, and it works all the time.

```html
if { (eval echo configure:1282: \"$ac_link\") 1>&5; (eval $ac_link) 2>&5; } && t$
  rm -rf conftest*
  eval "ac_cv_lib_$ac_lib_var=yes"
else
  echo "configure: failed program was:" >&5
  cat conftest.$ac_ext >&5
  rm -rf conftest*
  eval "ac_cv_lib_$ac_lib_var=yes"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instal pkgconfig or do change Makefile for you manual path

Note, asterisk make file not tested for your architecture.

But it opensource, so you are free test,do changes and commit. Or hire someone who can do that.